# Getting error routeNotificationFor() on laravel notifications

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I'm trying to send email to members on my app and I get the following error:

> production.ERROR: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::routeNotificationFor()
>   {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to
>   undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::routeNotificationFor() at
>   /var/www/vhosts/.../laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2483)

I have the members model with the `Notifiable` trait and the weird issue is that on my local machine the emails are delivered... The problem is on production...

**Any ideas?**

The notifications are fired with:

```php
Notification::send($members_to_notify, new CommMessage($communication));
```

And the `CommMessage`class is:

**CommMessage.php**

```php
namespace App\Notifications\Communications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Mail\Communications\Message as Mailable;

class CommMessage extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Queueable;

    private $communication;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($communication)
    {
        $this->communication = $communication;

    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return Mailable
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new Mailable($this->communication))->to($notifiable->email);
    }
}
```

The mailable `Message` class is:

**Message.php**

```php
namespace App\Mail\Communications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Message extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The appointment instance.
     *
     * @var Appointment
     */
    public $communication;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($communication)
    {
        $this->communication = $communication;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->replyTo($this->communication->school->email)
             ->markdown('emails.communications.message');

        $this->subject($this->communication->title);

        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $message->getHeaders()
                    ->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', json_encode([
                        'model_id' => $this->communication->id,
                        'model' => get_class($this->communication),
                        'email_type' => 11 //Communication message (EmailLogType)
                    ]));
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved. Code has no errors, I was using **Supervisor** to manage queues and I have forgot to restart it on production server.