# Undefined method routeNotificationFor() when using trait

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm using the Notifable trait from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) in Laravel 10.

Notifications work fine when using the User model.

Using a different model I get this error in the logs:

> production.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Models\Contractor::routeNotificationFor() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0):
> Call to undefined method App\Models\Contractor::routeNotificationFor() at
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:67)

The Contractor model has:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

and 

use Notifiable;
```

on it as per the User model and docs linked above.. It also has an `email` field (not that I'm using atm).

Firing the notification:

```
# Usually using the relationship
#$contractor = $this->model->contractor;
$contractor = Contractor::find(1);

if ($contractor)
{
     $contractor->notify(new JobContractor($this->model));
}
```

`get_class($contractor)` at this point says it's a `App\Models\Contractor` class and `$contractor` is set. `echo $contractor->email` does output the address so it is an instantiated model instance.

What else can I check here? Checking the definition of the traits in VSCode they seem to check out.

My `Contractor` class use(s) `Notifiable` trait which use(s) `RoutesNotifications` which has a `routeNotificationFor` function in it.

Edit 1:
To test it's not an issue with the Notification and Mailable I changed to the other method using the facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
```

```
if ($contractor)
{
    #$contractor->notify(new JobContractor($this->model));
    $user = User::find(1);
    Notification::send($user, new JobContractor($this->model));
}
```

That does work.

Edit 2:
I too am using queues like this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234937/getting-error-routenotificationfor-on-laravel-notifications?rq=2). However this is the same queue. I have restarted Supervisor and the server.